# Как заменить клик мыши нажатием клавиши в js?

Tags: javascript, события

Интересует, как на чистом js (без фреймворков), при помощи обработчиков событий (document.onkeydown и document.onmousedown) или иными способами, можно было бы заменить нажатие на ЛКМ и ПКМ нажатием на клавиши на клавиатуре.
Управлять курсором также при помощи мыши, но вместо левого клика, например, нажимать 'KeyQ' а вместо правого нажимать 'KeyW'.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А кнопки самой мышки должны работать или "клик" должен происходить ТОЛЬКО нажатием на определённую клавищу?

Comment: @EzioMercer лучше, конечно, если кнопки мыши будут работать.